# How do I change my Nintendo account email address?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate, nintendo-account

I recently got Smash ultimate. When I opened the game, it said about something that I could get by earning the gold points from the game. After earning the gold points, I checked the message again, but it said that a download code would be sent to the email address registered with my Nintendo account.

That email address has probably been deleted and I no longer have any means of accessing it.

I went to the Nintendo account settings online to change my email address, but I couldn’t figure out how. It kept asking me to verify my old email address.

How do I change the address linked to my Nintendo account and resend the download code?

Comment: If the site asks you to verify your old account, you might want to get in contact with Nintendo support and explain your situation to them. They'll probably understand if you tell them you no longer have access to your old mail account. You might even be able to ask them to resend the download code mail to the new address. As far as I know, even if you managed to change your address, there is no option (that I'm aware of) to resend the Piranha Plant code.